# Is there a way to use a specific TCPConn to make HTTP requests?

Tags: http, go, tcp

I am trying to set up a way to communicate between a central server running Go an a fleet of IoT devices (also running Go).

For each device, it connects to to the central server through a persistent TCPConn.  These devices are behind a router(s). The central server saves that connection and sends/receives messages through it.  Right now, this is fully functional and works.

However, now the message passing is getting complicated enough that the utility provided by HTTP rather than pure TCP is becoming necessary.

I have attempted to write a version of http.Transport that returns said connection.  However, I am unable to provide and return a valid connection from the the Dial/DialContext functions.

IoT Device

```golang
func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/foo", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %q", html.EscapeString(r.URL.Path))
    })

    tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "###.###.###.###:8533")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, tcpAddr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = conn.SetKeepAlive(true)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = conn.SetKeepAlivePeriod(time.Second * 10)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Listening")
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Central Server

```golang
func main() {
    tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", port)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    listener, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", tcpAddr)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    conn, err := listener.AcceptTCP()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Received conn, attempting to send HTTP through connection")

    dialFunc := func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
        return conn, nil
    }

    t := http.Transport{
        Dial: dialFunc,
    }

    client := http.Client{
        Transport: &t,
    }

    fmt.Println("Making request")
    res, err := client.Get("http://www.shouldNotMatter.com:8080/foo") // HANGS HERE
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Received response")
    defer res.Body.Close()

    if res.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
        bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        bodyString := string(bodyBytes)
        fmt.Println(bodyString)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(res)
    }
}
```

Upon using a debugger to see where it hangs, it seems that it gets stuck in a select statement during the pconn roundtrip.  Line 2420 in https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go?s=3397:10477

Comment: "I have attempted..." -- What have you attempted? Please include your code. What specific problems did you have with your code?

Comment: I've attached the standard solution.  However, it hangs in the indicated line.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to hang on that line. Do you mean it hangs waiting for `client.Get` to return?

Comment: Yes exactly.  And then within the Get, it hangs on a select statement within pconn.roundTrip().

Answer (score 4):

Create a type that returns an existing connection from a dial method:

```
type connDialer struct {
    c net.Conn
}

func (cd connDialer) Dial(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
    return cd.c, nil
}
```

Use the dial [method value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values) in a transport:

```
client := http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{Dial: connDialer{c}.Dial}}
```

where `c` is the existing `net.Conn`.

Try it on [the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wFdIQvibqQ2) (it works for at one request. It will fail when the client dials a second connection).

The overall approach is fragile. Consider using WebSockets, gRPC or other protocols that are designed to support bi-directional communication.

Comment: Thank you for this!  However, I believe this only works with publicly available urls.

Comment: @migsvult This approach makes no assumptions about how the specific connection was created. The peer does not need to be publicly addressable.

Comment: @migsvult Try it on [the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wFdIQvibqQ2) (it works for at one request. It will fail when the client dials a second connection).

Answer (score 0):

You missed the code on the client code. The client makes an idle connection to the server and does nothing with it so the connection will definitely hang up. You need to pass the connection to the HTTP server. This can be achieved by using `net/http.Serve` and passing a `net.Listener` to it.

```
type connListener struct {
    conn net.Conn
    ch chan struct{}
}
func (c connListener) Accept() (Conn, error) {
    if c.conn != nil {
        conn := c.conn
        c.conn = nil
        return conn, nil
    }
    <-c.ch
    return nil, errors.New("listener closed")
}
func (c connListener) Close() error {
    close(c.ch)
    return nil
}
func (c connListener) Addr() net.Addr {
    return c.conn.LocalAddr()
}

// call it like this
http.Serve(connListener{conn, make(chan struct{})}, nil)
```

BTW are you having the client connect to the server and then *reverse* the connection, making the client behave like an HTTP server and the server behave like the HTTP client? You might want to google "reverse http" for some information on this.